# How to workraound this TypeORM error, "EntityRepository is deprecated , use Repository.extend function instead"?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

However, I can't find any Repository.extend method in Repository class and there's nothing about it in the documentation. How to solve this?

typeorm version: "^0.3.0"

I'm using nest js and trying to create a custom repository.

Comment: I guess it's better to use `typeorm@0.2` for now. Also, see this PR: https://github.com/nestjs/typeorm/pull/384

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First of all:

```
npm install @nestjs/typeorm@next
```

**NOTE**

In my project **@nestjs/typeorm** version is `9.0.0-next.2` and **typeorm** version is `0.3.6`

Create a folder named database in the src of your project then create two files in (**typeorm-ex.decorator.ts** and **typeorm-ex.module.ts**)

```
// typeorm-ex.decorator.ts

import { SetMetadata } from "@nestjs/common";

export const TYPEORM_EX_CUSTOM_REPOSITORY = "TYPEORM_EX_CUSTOM_REPOSITORY";

export function CustomRepository(entity: Function): ClassDecorator {
  return SetMetadata(TYPEORM_EX_CUSTOM_REPOSITORY, entity);
}
```

And next file

```
// typeorm-ex.module.ts

import { DynamicModule, Provider } from "@nestjs/common";
import { getDataSourceToken } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";
import { TYPEORM_EX_CUSTOM_REPOSITORY } from "./typeorm-ex.decorator";

export class TypeOrmExModule {
  public static forCustomRepository<T extends new (...args: any[]) => any>(repositories: T[]): DynamicModule {
    const providers: Provider[] = [];

    for (const repository of repositories) {
      const entity = Reflect.getMetadata(TYPEORM_EX_CUSTOM_REPOSITORY, repository);

      if (!entity) {
        continue;
      }

      providers.push({
        inject: [getDataSourceToken()],
        provide: repository,
        useFactory: (dataSource: DataSource): typeof repository => {
          const baseRepository = dataSource.getRepository<any>(entity);
          return new repository(baseRepository.target, baseRepository.manager, baseRepository.queryRunner);
        },
      });
    }

    return {
      exports: providers,
      module: TypeOrmExModule,
      providers,
    };
  }
}
```

Open your AppModule and modify it like the following:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mssql',
      ...
      entities: [Photo],
    }),
    TypeOrmExModule.forCustomRepository([PhotoRepository]),
    ...
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    AppService
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

You can create your customer repository like the following :

```
@CustomRepository(Photo)
export class PhotoRepository extends Repository<Photo> {
    public async getAllPhoto() {
        const query = this.createQueryBuilder('photo')
            .where('photo.isPublished = :isPublished', { isPublished: true })
        const photos = await query.getMany()
        return photos
    }
}
```

Everything works perfectly.

**Thanks to** [**@anchan828**](https://gist.github.com/anchan828/9e569f076e7bc18daf21c652f7c3d012)

Comment: To those arriving here from Google: this certainly works, but is much more complicated than [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74635579/2065427)

Answer (score 14):

With the current version of TypeORM, it's possible to implement a custom repository in the following way utilizing DataSource.

```js
// user.repository.ts
@Injectable()
export class UsersRepository extends Repository<UsersEntity> {
  constructor(private dataSource: DataSource) {
    super(UsersEntity, dataSource.createEntityManager());
  }

  async getById(id: string) {
    return this.findOne({ where: { id } });
  }
  // ...
}
```

The repository is then injected into the service.

```js
// user.service.ts
export class UserService {
  constructor(private readonly userRepository: UserRepository) {}

  async getById(id: string): Promise<User> {
    return this.userRepository.getById(id);
  }
  // ...
}
```

and the module has imports for the feature and the repository as a provider.

```js
// user.module.ts
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserEntity])],
    // ...
  ],
  providers: [UserService, UserRepository],
  // ...
})
export class UserModule {}
```

Comment: Just tried this with nestjs v10.2.7, nestjs/typeorm v10.0.0 and typeorm v0.3.17 and it works. Cleanest solution to this that I've seen yet.

Answer (score 6):

In the new version of TypeORM (0.3.*), I am changing custom repositories to services.
Based on connection to multiple official documentation databases.
https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#multiple-databases

Custom repository

```js
  @EntityRepository(Person)
  export class PersonRepository extends Repository<Person> {...}
```

Custom repository as Service

```js
  @Injectable()
  export class PersonRepository {
    constructor(private dataSource: DataSource) { }

    exampleQueryBuilder() {
      return this.dataSource
          .getRepository(Person)
          .createQueryBuilder() ...
    }
```

Repository injection

```js
  @Injectable()
  export class PersonService {
    constructor(
      @Inject(PersonRepository)
      private readonly personRepository: PersonRepository,
    ) {}
```

Comment: This approach is much simpler and cleaner. It also works for those who were extending from the `AbstractRepository` in earlier versions of TypeORM.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to create a separated repository file and the entity will be injected to the service just like that:

```
import { Injectable, NotFoundException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Task } from './task.entity';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';


@Injectable()
export class TasksService {
 constructor(
  @InjectRepository(Task)
  private taskRepository: Repository<Task>
 ) {}

 async getTasksById(id: number): Promise<Task> {
   const found = await this.taskRepository.findOne({ where: { id: id 
   }});
 }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The way I could solve this error is the following:

First, I created the file `datasource.ts`, I  also declared the datasource, it follows the same structure as the `ormconfig.js` file:

```
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
require('dotenv').config();

export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
  type: 'mongodb',
  url: process.env.MONGO_URI,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  synchronize: true,
  logging: true,
  database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
  entities: ['dist/entities/*.js'],
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

AppDataSource.initialize()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Data Source has been initialized!');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('Error during Data Source initialization', err);
  });
```

And, after that, I created a Custom Repository:

```
import { AppDataSource } from '@CustomDataSource';
import { Product } from '@Entities';
import { CreateProductDto, UpdateProductDto } from '@Products';

const dataSource = AppDataSource;
export const ProductRepository = 
dataSource.getMongoRepository(Product).extend({
async findOneById(id: number): Promise<Product> {
    const product = await ProductRepository.findOne({ where: { id }});
    return product;
  },
async findMany(): Promise<Product[]> {
    const products = await ProductRepository.find();
    return products;
  },
});
```

In this way, you don't have to add the repositories in `TypeORMModule.forFeature([])`, for each module in which you are working.
Note that now, we don't call `this`, we call `ProductRepository` and the method directly.

Answer (score 1):

The process, that have worked for me:

a)Define your Entity: (**task.entity.ts**)

```
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class Task {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  title: string;
}
```

b)Define your repository (**tasks.repository.ts**)

```
import { Injectable, NotFoundException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { DataSource, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Task } from './task.entity';

@Injectable()
export class TasksRepository extends Repository<Task> {
  constructor(private dataSource: DataSource) {
    super(Task, dataSource.createEntityManager());
  }

  async getById(id: string): Promise<Task> {
    const found = await this.findOneBy({ id });

    if (!found) {
      throw new NotFoundException(`Task with ID "${id}" not found`);
    }

    return found;
  }
}
```

c)Controller (**tasks.controller.ts**)

```
import {
  Controller,
  Get,
  Param,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { TasksService } from './tasks.service';
import { Task } from './task.entity';

@Controller('tasks')
export class TasksController {
  constructor(private tasksService: TasksService) {}

  @Get('/:id')
  getTaskById(@Param('id') id: string): Promise<Task> {
    return this.tasksService.getTaskById(id);
  }
}
```

d)Define module (**tasks.module.ts**)

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Task } from './task.entity';
import { TasksController } from './tasks.controller';
import { TasksRepository } from './tasks.repository';
import { TasksService } from './tasks.service';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Task])],
  controllers: [TasksController],
  providers: [TasksService, TasksRepository],
})
export class TasksModule {}
```

e)And in the root module (**app.module.ts**) - NOT FOR PRODUCTION

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TasksModule } from './tasks/tasks.module';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TasksModule,
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 5432,
      username: 'postgres',
      password: 'postgres',
      database: 'task-management',
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      synchronize: true,
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Note**: autoLoadEntities, loads automatically any entity defined. This must follow the name name_entity.entity.ts

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

As refer to the [related PR](https://github.com/nestjs/typeorm/pull/1233), the migration is work in progress. You can checkout the latest progress by using:

```
yarn add @nestjs/typeorm@next
```

You can use custom dynamic module as a workaround, like [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anchan828/9e569f076e7bc18daf21c652f7c3d012) for now.

Answer (score 0):

I created a utility method `provideCustomRepository` to simplify overriding a repository with nestjs / typeorm 0.3.x

https://gist.github.com/rhutchison/a530d89c37f1978a48dcee4bf2418cb7

```
import { Provider, Type } from '@nestjs/common';
import { getDataSourceToken, getRepositoryToken } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { DataSource, DataSourceOptions, Repository } from 'typeorm';

export function provideCustomRepository<T>(
  entity: Type<T>,
  repository: Type<Repository<T>>,
  dataSource?: DataSource | DataSourceOptions | string
): Provider {
  return {
    provide: getRepositoryToken(entity),
    inject: [getDataSourceToken(dataSource)],
    useFactory(dataSource: DataSource) {
      const baseRepository = dataSource.getRepository(entity);
      return new repository(
        baseRepository.target,
        baseRepository.manager,
        baseRepository.queryRunner
      );
    },
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://gist.github.com/rhutchison/a530d89c37f1978a48dcee4bf2418cb7.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -3):

[TypeORM CHANGELOG.md](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

In order to extend UserRepository functionality you can use .extend method of Repository class

[Example](https://typeorm.io/custom-repository)
// user.repository.ts

```
export const UserRepository = dataSource.getRepository(User).extend({...})
```

Comment: doesnt help the old implementation of extending repositories suing @Entityrepository decorator