# Nest custom repository function not define

Tags: repository, nestjs, typeorm

I have a small question about custom repositories in nestjs.

I have the following logic when a request comes in (for example for user entity).

A controller for the user requests -> service -> repository calls custom function.

So i have the following repository:
[image]

I inject the repository in service class
[image]

And register in module file
[image]

But when calling signup function I got error:
[image]

I did research and also try to add  @InjectRepository(UserRepository) in service but it sill not work
Environments:

1. node: 16.13.0
2. @nestjs/typeorm": "^8.1.4",
3. typeorm: "^0.3.7"
4. nestjs: 8.2.8

Thank in advance

Comment: I can handle this issue by change repository
```
@Injectable()
export class UserRepository {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private readonly usersRepository: Repository<User>,
  ) {}
```
But it something like I inject in service directly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to workraound this TypeORM error, "EntityRepository is deprecated , use Repository.extend function instead"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71557301/how-to-workraound-this-typeorm-error-entityrepository-is-deprecated-use-repo)

Comment: `@EntityRepository` is deprecated in recent versions of TypeORM. Please have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71557301/how-to-workraound-this-typeorm-error-entityrepository-is-deprecated-use-repo

Comment: thank Thierry Falvo, I tried it before but it not work for me

Answer (score 0):

try **BaseRepository** in [typeorm-transactional-cls-hooked](https://github.com/odavid/typeorm-transactional-cls-hooked)

```
@EntityRepository(UserEntity)
export class UserRepository extends BaseRepository<UserEntity>{
.
.
.
}
```